# Images not being displayed on webserver

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am new in spring development. I am creating a small application wherein images will be uploaded onto the web server and then displayed in jsp pages. So far, this is working fine at my localhost

Image uploading path is (on localhost)

`E:\S30102015\public\WebContent\public_images`

I am displaying image in jsp page using

`<img width='100%' height='100%' src= '<c:url value='/public_images/"+response.filename+"'/>'/>`

Everything is working fine on localhost, but after creating a `war` file, the image portion is not working.

Can somebody guide me on this issue?
1. Can the images be written in war file ?
2. If NO to 1, then what should I do ?

Edit :

My server path is -

```
public-html
|
---cgi-bin
---WEB-INF----
    |
    --- classes
    --- lib
---myWar
```

So should I have another folder say, `images` in `public_html` and upload all images in it ?

Comment: Save the images outside the applications folder, i.e. /var/media/images.

Comment: @stefan means in war location